# How to use ObjectBox and Unique with box.put(Collections)

Tags: unique, objectbox

I want to put a whole collection of entities into a `Box` with the `put(Collections)` method, however, there will be a unique key on the `Entity`.

I know you can catch errors with try catch, but I want to be able to do an update on the error `Entity`, plus carry on and do any remaining

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already discovered, the `@Unique` conflict strategy is currently discussed here:
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/509

(for future reference)